# Multivalued Dependency transitivity property

Tags: database-normalization, transitive-dependency

I understand MVD complement and MVD Augmentation. However, it is difficult to understand MVD transitive dependency.

For reference I have read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency

X =>=> Y and Y =>=> Z. How can we conclude X =>=> Z-Y?

Please also clear coalescence.

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post. Please show your research--What sort of similar proofs have you found, or even, what can you do having researched how to prove a rule/theorem? What is your textbook name & edition & what does it say that is relevant? What can you apply from "understanding" complement & augmentation rules/theorems? What have you tried & where did you get stuck? See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Plug the 3 special cases into the definition of MVD & show LHS iff/when  RHS.

Comment: DB programming & design does involve MVDs. But not use or proof of such a rule, which instead is part of CS curriculum & theoretical justification for algorithms & heuristics that we would use. So it's reasonable to consider this question off-topic here. [ask] [help/on-topic] [help/dont-ask] [help]. **An appropriate edit of this** is better asked on another site **if on-topic there** like [cs.se] or [math.se] (with this deleted here). PS What did you learn from researching & applying proofs of Armstrong's axioms?